# Returning document URI after an element search

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to do a search based on an element value. This should return the element value and the document URI having that matching element value. I have written a code as below which is well returning the element value. Not getting document URI. How to get both.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
<results>{
let $x := cts:element-values(fn:QName("http://example.com/dataset","name"), (), ("frequency-order","document"), cts:query(
  <and-query xmlns="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <word-query>
      <text>paramedical</text>
    </word-query>
    <directory-query>
      <uri>/dataset/</uri>
    </directory-query>
  </and-query>
))
for $dataset in $x
return
(
<result>
  <name>{$dataset}</name>
  <reference>{cts:uris($dataset)}</reference>
</result>
)
}</results>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for $tuple in cts:value-tuples(
  (
    cts:element-reference(fn:QName("http://example.com/dataset","name")),
    cts:uri-reference()
  ),
  ("frequency-order","document"),
  $query
)
return $tuple
```

You'll need the URI lexicon turned on.

Comment: This work for me. Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Since this answers your question, [please mark it as "accepted"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: do we have an option to return only value of the first occurrence of name element in each document. Now in same document we have name element coming directly under root element and also as child element of other elements. It's returning all name values and same URI in result.